# Acquiring Facebook publish_action for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, publish-actions

I have been trying to get permission for `publish_action`. I have got a response from the reviewing team that `The following items were not reviewed due to general issues with your app: publish_actions`
They haven't mentioned that issues they found so that I can fix and submit for review again.

can any one help me in this regard?

Thank you

Comment: Is there no feedback at all? You can try to post in this FB group; the reviewing team is there active as well: https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Comment: ahh, thanks so much Flax. I got the FB reviewing team.